# can anyone tell me why my product description is not flowing right in virtualmart 2.06

Tags: php, css, virtuemart

http://cookstown.wsisrdev.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=1&virtuemart_category_id=1&Itemid=114

can anyone tell me why my text is looking justified in my product desription please this is virutalmart 2.06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css file, position.css, the text-alignment is set to `text-align: center;` for the `<body>` element.
That will affect everything on the page.

Remove it, or add something like:

> ul{ text-align: left;}